# How to delete commit history in gerrit in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, gerrit

I have done some incorrect commits using gerrit in eclipse. Now, I want to delete my commit history.

*Doing hard reset to the original head i.e. before any commit does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Open command prompt or git bash.

`git revert HEAD~1..HEAD`

It will checkout the previous commit. It will get you in to a state called detached head. create new branch from this point and continue your work,

if the commit is a merge add -m flag

`git revert -m HEAD~1..HEAD`